# Call super method from Xcore operation

Tags: super, eclipse-emf, emf, eclipse-emf-ecore, xcore

I have the following declarations in Xcore:

```java
class ValueBase { ... }

class ValueArray extends ValueBase
{
  int size
  double [] values
  String valueUnit

  op boolean isValueEqual(Value v) 
  {
    if (!(v instanceof IValueArray))
    {
      return false
    }
    val other = v as IValueArray;
    return Iterables.elementsEqual(this.values, other.values);
  }

  op boolean equals(Value v)
  {
    return super.equals(v) && isValueEqual(v) && 
      (v instanceof IValueArray) &&
      Objects.equals(valueUnit, (v as IValueArray).valueUnit)
  }
}
```

`ValueBase` implements its own `equals()` method. In the concrete class `ValueArray`, I want to call `super.equals()` to compare the base class' common fields and then do comparisons specific to the concrete class.

But Xcore complains about that code that it "`Couldn't resolve reference to JvmIdentifiableElement super`".

How can I call the `equals()`-method from the super class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to make some assumptions about the code that you don't show here, but the short answer is that it works. You're calling `super.equals` correctly. But as I said, I had to make some assumptions. So here is what I have that seems to be fine with Xcore.

```java
package soxcore

import com.google.common.base.Objects
import com.google.common.collect.Iterables

class ValueBase {
    op boolean equals(Value v)
    {
        return true;
    }
}

class ValueArray extends ValueBase, IValueArray
{
  int size

  op boolean isValueEqual(Value v) 
  {
    if (!(v instanceof IValueArray))
    {
      return false
    }
    val other = v as IValueArray;
    return Iterables.elementsEqual(this.values, other.values);
  }

  op boolean equals(Value v)
  {
    return super.equals(v) && isValueEqual(v) && 
      (v instanceof IValueArray) &&
      Objects.equal(valueUnit, (v as IValueArray).valueUnit)
  }
}

class Value extends ValueBase
{

}

interface IValueArray {
    double[] values
    String valueUnit
}
```

No complaints from Xcore. So am I missing something?

Comment: Thanks for answering. I had also asked Ed in the Eclipse Community Forums and he mentioned that earlier, there have been a few bugs related to super. And since I am using an older version (because my customer's target platform is not yet up to date), this might be the cause. I didn't have the time to double-check with a new version, but I'll stick to the bug-theory until proven otherwise and give you the credit for answering. As a workaround, I have implemented the super-logic in every subclass now. Sucks, but what can you do ;-)